# PHP gets empty $_FILES var on JavaScript file upload

Tags: javascript, php

I'am trying to upload a file from js to php like this

```
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', uploadedFile);

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.onload = function () {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
                var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                console.log(response);
            }
        };

        request.open('POST', settings.restUri + 'files');
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        request.send(formData);
```

As a result my request payload looks like this

```
            ------WebKitFormBoundaryRl1Q67A1DDBjvKCU
            Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="user.svg"

            Content-Type: image/svg+xml


            ------WebKitFormBoundaryRl1Q67A1DDBjvKCU--
```

but `$_FILES` variable is empty on PHP side, what's wrong?

Comment: Try to comment out this line: request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

Comment: It works, but why? (add like a comment, i ll mark an answer)

Comment: new FormData is multipart/form-data if i am not mistaken.

Comment: Added and added the reason. please consider accepting my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line:

`request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");`

The reason is emphasised in bold.

> The FormData object lets you compile a set of key/value pairs to send using XMLHttpRequest. It is primarily intended for use in sending
>   form data, but can be used independently from forms in order to
>   transmit keyed data. The **transmitted data is in the same format** that
>   the form's submit() method would use to send the data **if the form's**
>   **encoding type were set to multipart/form-data**.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)